# Application design recommendations for embedded Raspberry Pi with screen reading GPIO & i2c

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am creating a simple car dashboard cluster using a Raspberry Pi 4 with a 7in screen and using an 8 channel ADC hat and the GPIO pins for sensor input.

The GPIO pins will be used to read the state of various switches in the car using a step down converter so that when a switch is on 12v from that switch will be converted to 3.3V and send to a GPIO pin so it will be high.

The ADC will be used to read the values of various 5V sensors in the car like oil pressure, coolant temp etc.

The screen is a basic HDMI 7in screen with the Pi mounted behind it and I plan to 3D print a new gauge cluster bezel to fit everything into the stock location. I have a Mausberry power controller so that the Pi will turn on with key on and turn off again with key off. I have modified the Pi so it boots from SSD and starts up pretty quickly.

I have used simple Python programs to read the data from the ADC over i2c and the GPIO pins and output it, no issues there. I have found a nice Javascript based library called Justgage which looks like a great way to display my data in a simple HTML page and have designed my page layout with the various gauges and lights that will eventually have the data read from the ADC or GPIO pins.

What I need some advice on is how best to architect the overall solution, I have all the various parts but need to integrate them. I want to minimise the amount of software running on the Pi so it boots quickly.

At the moment when the Pi boots it auto loads Chromium and opens my page I have created but I need a method to be able to read the i2c and GPIO data and then refresh the elements in the HTML page. The Justgage library supports refreshing the data so that I don't have to refresh the page and would like a method to read the data every second or so and then call the Justgage refresh function.

All the examples of this sort of model I can see online use a webserver running on the Pi but as the screen is directly connected to the Pi I don't actually need a webserver and would like to minimise the amount of software running for reliability and boot times.

Sorry for the long first post and appreciate any guidance. Happy to post the HTML if that would be of any help.

Cheers
Matt.

Comment: Hi Matt! Seems like a pretty cool project you are building there! I'm a huge Raspberry Pi enthusiast. I understand your concern about having unnecessary apps running on the pi... If you ask me, I would use node.js and sockets to emit events to the dashboard. But if you have no node.js experience, maybe try to put together all the data of the sensors in a JSON file in the same directory of the index.html and have an ajax call reading that file every X milliseconds. I'm not sure, but maybe in order for the ajax call to work you may need an http server. I would suggest nginx in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will look into the JSON file for a start!